# How to start Spring JMS listener container manually

Tags: java, spring, jms

I have a server side application that consumes message from an JMS queue. I use Spring listener container like this:

```
<jms:listener-container connection-factory="myConnectionFactory"
                        ..........
                        concurrency="4-8">
    <jms:listener id="myListener" destination="my.ems.queue" ref="listenerBean" method="method"/>
</jms:listener-container>
```

This works fine.

One problem of this is that the listener starts to consume JMS message as soon as it is setup. However, some of the beans the `listenerBean` depends take some time to initialize (It needs to populate some data from database).

Therefore, if the service starts up with some pending JMS message in the queue, it will try to serve it before data is populated completed. This causes some error.

My question is that how can I not start listener automatically until a later stage when data is fully populated, so that I can call the `start()` method to manually start it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `autoStartup` property on DMLC to keep it from starting until you choose to call `start()`.

Another way is to make sure the connection factory is not created before your other dependent beans are ready.

```
<bean class="..." name="myConnectionFactory" depends-on="importantOtherBean"/>
```

Comment: @Peter Setting the `autoStartup` to false didn't help me in this case. Even before manually starting it, my listener keeps being triggered when a message is received...
Can you please check my question for more info ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43207792/not-able-to-stop-mqueue-listener